# How can I start a timer on keydown and stop on keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I would like to be able to press the spacebar and left arrow key at the same time and have a timer start for ten seconds. If the user stops pressing the key then the timer should stop as well and the result should be cancelled.
I have already tried to use the clearInterval() method.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration;
  var minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      window.open('1.html', '_self')
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var start = timeFunction = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 1 * 10;
  var display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};

var timesdown = 0;

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'Space' && 'LeftArrow') {
    if (timesdown == 0) {
      start();
      timesdown = 1;
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'Space' && 'LeftArrow') {
    timesdown = 0
    clearInterval(startTimer);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

When I press down on the key, the timer continues to try to restart but when I lift up the timer continues counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems. First, you are using `keypress` instead of `keydown` and `keypress` will not detect the arrow keys.

You also have the `event.code` wrong. It's `ArrowLeft`, not `LeftArrow`.

Events are also only processed one at a time. `event.code` cannot be `'Space'` and `'LeftArrow'` at the same time. `event.code` is one variable!

Since events are processed only one at a time you need extra logic to capture that state.

The code below is a working example, correcting all of the above problems.

```js
var intervalID = false;
var spaceDown = false;
var arrowDown = false;
var spaceUp = false;
var arrowUp = false;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
          
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      console.log("window.open('1.html', '_self')");
    }
  }, 1000);
}


var start = timeFunction = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 1 * 10,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};

var timesdown = 0

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  
  if (event.code == 'Space') {
    spaceDown = true;
    spaceUp = false;
  }

  if (event.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
    arrowDown = true;
    arrowUp = false;
  }

  if (spaceDown && arrowDown) {
    if (timesdown == 0) {
      start();
      timesdown = 1;
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

  if (event.code == 'Space') {
    spaceDown = false;
    spaceUp = true;
  }

  if (event.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
    arrowDown = false;
    arrowUp = true;
  }

  if (spaceUp && arrowUp) {
    timesdown = 0;
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="time"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.
You will need a reference of the setInterval to clear the interval. I assigned the setInterval to a variable, and later clearing Interval using the variable.

```js
var timeInterval;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration;
  var minutes, seconds;
  timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      window.open('1.html', '_self')
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var start = timeFunction = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 1 * 10;
  var display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};

var timesdown = 0;

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'Space' && 'LeftArrow') {
    if (timesdown == 0) {
      start();
      timesdown = 1;
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'Space' && 'LeftArrow') {
    timesdown = 0
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```